# How can I save my data from a listview fragment?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a navigation drawer in main activity and a listview in one of my fragments. If my respective fragment changes to another fragment I lose the data in listview. How can I save it without a big fuss? In a shared preferences file or a database?

Comment: its upon to you, pick better method. large number of data -> db, smaller amout (e.g. some strings) -> prefs would in handle quickly and may be sufficient

Comment: Then I think I will try the shared prefs as I have just some strings and a date format. Thank you!